# SSIS Package with Target Version SQL Server 2014 throwing errors in VS 2019

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-data-tools

I have a SSIS project which was developed with target server version 2014. I have SQL Server 2018 installed in my machine and VS 2019. SSDT is also installed.

When I open the SSIS project in VS 2019, I get so many errors as following:

1. `Error loading xyz.dtsx: There was an exception while loading Script Task from XML: System.Exception: The Script Task "ST_241f23c065a942b691fa61080dfb01f2" uses version 15.0 script that is not supported in this release of Integration Services. To run the package, use the Script Task to create a new VSTA script. In most cases, scripts are converted automatically to use a supported version, when you open a SQL Server Integration Services package in %SQL_PRODUCT_SHORT_NAME% Integration Services. at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.ScriptTask.LoadFromXML(XmlElement elemProj, IDTSInfoEvents events)`
2. `Error loading xyz.dtsx: The component metadata for "Create New Metadata Types" could not be upgraded to the newer version of the component. The PerformUpgrade method failed.`
3. `Validation error. CIC Intelligent Tagging SSIS.Pipeline: The component metadata for "Intelligent Tagging, clsid {C1463F00-2FAF-4AD4-A212-C9D9CCB54575}" could not be upgraded to the newer version of the component. The PerformUpgrade method failed.`
4. `Validation error. Parse XML Metadata: Parse XML Metadata: The component metadata for "Parse XML Metadata, clsid {C1463F00-2FAF-4AD4-A212-C9D9CCB54575}" could not be upgraded to the newer version of the component. The PerformUpgrade method failed.`

And many more...

I am not sure what am I missing.

Comment: Looks like your SSIS Script Tasks Needs to rebuild. You Need to Open Each SSIS Package and Build the Script Task and save them

Comment: @Roshan It does not work.

Comment: Check whether your project solution is on which type(VB or C#). IF not inline with the script task change to appropriate. Also, Change the Script task version and try